# Supremum distance in Scipy python

Tags: python, vector, distance

I am trying to find all types of Minkowski distances between 2 vectors. I am using scipy distances to get these distances. The scipy function for Minkowski distance is:

```
distance.minkowski(a, b, p=?)
```

- if p = 1, its called Manhattan Distance
- if p = 2, its called Euclidean Distance
- if p = infinite, its called Supremum Distance

I want to know what value of 'p' should I put to get the supremum distance or there is any other formulae or library I can use?

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: @MFisherKDX python 2.7

Comment: Try `float('inf')`

Comment: Or alternatively: ```numpy.inf```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

float('inf') should work

```
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.minkowski([1,2,3], [1,1,1], p=float('inf'))
2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist
>>> dist.chebyshev([1,2,3], [1,1,1])
2.0
```

The Chebyshev distance is another name for the Supremum distance and is built into the library.